# ml-auto and mr-auto are not working in react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Navbar, Nav, Container}from 'react-bootstrap'

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant='dark' expand="lg" collapseOnSelect>
              <Container>
                  <Navbar.Brand href="/">RafShop</Navbar.Brand>
                  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className='ml-auto'> 
                      <Nav.Link  href="/cart">Cart</Nav.Link>
                      <Nav.Link href="/login">Sign In</Nav.Link> 
                     </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
              </Container>  
            </Navbar>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: Please explain ur question a little bit more

Comment: I think for Bootstrap classes to work you need to import the Boostrap css inside your components.  Just do  `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` inside your root (App.js)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "ml-auto" which is deprecated, use "ms-auto"

Comment: That's true for [tag:bootstrap-5], but this question is tagged with [tag:bootstrap-4].